# Increment score, jQuery quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators, increment, slickquiz

I have been developing a jQuery quiz and I have been able to add the value of each answer together, I would like to add a function to the quiz that would allow for specific values added to a set of variables after each question has been answered.

I have included a jsFiddle, you can see when each question is clicked its the third question before any value is registered, and if a forth question is added, the incremented value is added three times.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jamcrowe/ta7LZ/1/

```
            // Answers to each question add these values to finalResult
     var value = {
     'question0'   : { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4 },
     'question1'   : { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4 },
     'question2'   : { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4 }
     };

          // The next question to present after each response
     var END = null;
     var nextQuestion = {
        'question0'   : { one: 'question1',   two: 'question1',  three: 'question1', four: 'question1',  },
       'question1'   : { one: 'question2',   two: 'question2',  three: 'question2', four: 'question2',  },
       'question2'  : { one: END,   two: END,  three: END, four: END,  },
   }; 

     // Show just the first question
     $('.ques').hide();
     $('#question0').fadeIn();

     var outcome = 0;

    $('.option').click(function(){

       increment();

       var answer = $(this).attr('value');
       var question = $(this).attr('name');

      outcome += value[question][answer];

      $('#' + question).delay(500).fadeOut(function(){
        var questionNext = nextQuestion[question][answer];
        if (questionNext == END){
            var finalResult = 'result ' + outcome;
            alert("Values added together : " + finalResult);
        }
        else {
            $('#' + questionNext).delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });

   });

    var online = 0;
    var creative = 0;
    var technical = 0;
    var analyst = 0;
   var managerial = 0;

    function  increment() {
    $('#q1a').click(function(){
        creative +=5;
        online ++;
        managerial ++;

    });
    $('#q2a').click(function(){
        creative +=5;
        online ++;
        managerial ++;

    });
    $('#q3a').click(function(){
        creative +=5;
        online ++;
        managerial ++;

    });
    $('#q4a').click(function(){
        creative +=5;
        online ++;
        managerial ++;

    });
    alert(creative);
    }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jamcrowe/ta7LZ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a two-part answer to what you're seeing:

First, every time you run the `increment` function, you bind a new click event to the `div`s with `id` `q1a`, `q2a`, `q3a` and `q4a`. What this means is that if you have multiple `click` events bound to one div, one click will run the event multiple times.

Next, these click events on `q1a`, `q2a`, etc. run AFTER the `$('.option')` click event. Therefore, when you see the second alert at 0 points, the variable `creative` is added to AFTER this alert is fired. You can see this by adding a `console.log()` statement inside your `q2a` click event like this:

```
$('#q2a').click(function(){
    creative +=5;
    online ++;
    managerial ++;
    console.log("q2a",creative);
});
```

Overall, you should either set up the click events inside of your `increment` function at the beginning of the script OR identify which div was clicked and add values according to this - DON'T add so many click events.

Hopefully this is helpful - I can answer further questions if you have any!